# how to stop parallax scrolling when collision happened in mono game?

Tags: monogame

I am doing a small car racing game on mono game, for the road and obstacle I am using parallax scrolling effect. when the car hits the obstacle, I need the road also stop the scrolling effect. I can't use the same way stop the car to stop the road, because they are not intersect with each other. How can I do this?
here is my collision manager

```
public class CollisionManager : GameComponent
    {
        private RacingCar car;
        private Obstacle obstacle;
        private Road road;
        public CollisionManager(Game game,RacingCar car,
            Obstacle obstacle, Road road) : base(game)
        {
            this.car = car;
            this.obstacle = obstacle;
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //get the boundary of the car
            //get the boundary of the obstacle
            //if the car boundary intersects with the obstacle boundary 
            // stop the program 
            Rectangle obstacleRect1 = obstacle.getBound1();
            Rectangle obstacleRect2 = obstacle.getBound2();
            Rectangle carRect = car.getBound();
            if (obstacleRect1.Intersects(carRect) ||obstacleRect2.Intersects(carRect))
            {
                obstacle.Speed = new Vector2(0, 0);
                car.Speed = new Vector2(0, 0);
                //road.Speed = new Vector2(0, 0);
                //I want do something here, but I can't make getBound funcaiton here,

                
            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
    }
```

getbound funcation for car and obstacle

```
 public Rectangle getBound()
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, tex.Width, tex.Height);
        }
```

```
 public Rectangle getBound1()
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)position1.X, (int)position1.Y, tex.Width, tex.Height);
        }
        public Rectangle getBound2()
        {
            return new Rectangle((int)position2.X, (int)position2.Y, tex.Width, tex.Height);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you are yet to give more details, but anyhow I'll try to answer. I can't see the implementation of parallax effect in your given code. I can see that the object `CollisionManager` is checking the collisions with the Car and obstacle objects, and I don't find any major issues with the said code. However, I think **trying to stop the scrolling effect inside this class is not a good idea**; Not that it is impossible, but your code will only become messy and harder to maintain/understand.

I feel a better approach would be to make your CollisionManager to set a bool. After this, wherever your scrolling logic is, it should see this bool value and change the scrolling as you desire.

So First, make a `public static bool` field inside your `CollisionManger` class, such as

```
public static bool HasCollided=false;
```

This field indicates whether the collision has taken place or not. The `CollisionManger` object now checks for collision and sets it to true in case a collision occurs. So, you need to change your existing `Update()` method inside the `CollisionManager` class as

```
public class CollisionManager : GameComponent
{
    private RacingCar car;
    private Obstacle obstacle;
    private Road road;
    public CollisionManager(Game game,RacingCar car,
        Obstacle obstacle, Road road) : base(game)
    {
        this.car = car;
        this.obstacle = obstacle;
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //get the boundary of the car
        //get the boundary of the obstacle
        //if the car boundary intersects with the obstacle boundary 
        // stop the program 
        Rectangle obstacleRect1 = obstacle.getBound1();
        Rectangle obstacleRect2 = obstacle.getBound2();
        Rectangle carRect = car.getBound();
        if (obstacleRect1.Intersects(carRect) ||obstacleRect2.Intersects(carRect))
        {
            obstacle.Speed = new Vector2(0, 0);
            car.Speed = new Vector2(0, 0);
            //road.Speed = new Vector2(0, 0);

            Game1.HasCollided = true; //This is all you need here...

        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Now, where you have the logic of scrolling, you only scroll if this field is true.

I am going to assume your scrolling is done in the `Update()` method of your default `Game1` class. (Maybe you made it in a different class or renamed it so please understand and apply the changes in that class only)

For the sake of completion, Let's say your said Update function looked like this:

```
public override void Update()
{
     .... //Your code

     .... //Your logic of parallax scrolling

     .... //Your remaining code
}
```

Now, you should change it to something like this

```
public override void Update()
{
     .... //Your code
     
     if(CollisionManager.HasCollided == false)//Only scroll if collision has not happened yet
     {
         .... //Your logic of parallax scrolling
     }

     .... //Your remaining code
}
```

EDIT: Also, whenever you need to restart your game, you need to set `CollisionManager.HasCollided` to false.